# Сортировка буквенной части составной (алфавитно-числовой) строки

Tags: java, строки, сортировка

Есть строки со словами:

```
кар1л у кл124ары 4укра3л к0ораллы
```

Необходимо отсортировать слова по алфавиту без учета чисел:

```
кар1л кл123ары к0ораллы у 4укра3л
```

Есть решение с разбором на подстроки. Заменой цифр на "" (replaceAll) и сортировкой полученных строк как элементов list. Как выстроить в том же порядке начальные данные?

**UPD**: В данный момент функциональный кусок обработки токена (newString) выглядит примерно так:

```
   newString = newString.replaceAll("\\d","");
   list.add(newString);

   Collections.sort(list);
```

**UPD-2**: В конечном итоге реализовано с помощью конструкции:

splitted - это начальный массив подстрок.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (splitted.length - 1); i++) {
        if (splitted[i].replaceAll("\\d", "").compareTo(splitted[i + 1].replaceAll("\\d", "")) > 0) {
            temp = splitted[i];
            splitted[i] = splitted[i + 1];
            splitted[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Как правильно реализовать?

Comment: Как должна быть отсортирована строка `у 1234 укра3л` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте массив перестановок. Сначала это массив с натуральными числами в возрастающем порядке. Одновременно с перестановкой обработанных строк представляете массив. По завершению сортировки в `a[i]` будет номер строки исходного массива строк.

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант - более экономный по ресурсам - написать собственный [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), который будет пропускать цифры при сравнении элементов. Потом сортировать им исходный список строк.

Comment: спасибо, была мысль о Компараторе, но также по условию нужен один "сырой" метод, принимающий и возвращающий строку.

Comment: @joker сырой это как? Компаратор вы можете и анонимным классом объявить прямо внутри метода.

Comment: с сигнатурой типа String sortWords(String s). Видимо, подразумевается чисто алгоритмическое решение с массивами.

Comment: @joker может `List<String>`?

Comment: сортировка "чистых" (без цифр) слов сейчас идёт с помощью List, вот надо в том же порядке расставить изначальные слова.